# Formatting footnotes as a table (not footnotes for tables!)

Tags: tables, footnotes, linguistics

Is there some way a person could format footnotes as a table?

What I'm trying to do is put translations and transliterations from English to Japanese in footnotes on my pages in the form

```
       WORD ---> IPA SPELLING ---> JAPANESE TRANSLATION
```

I'd like to keep each column aligned (as in a table!) without having to set the spacing manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put a tabular inside a footnote.  So it's easy to define a command to insert translation footnotes.  The command I've created takes 3 arguments, and puts them into a table inside a footnote.  By defining one column of the table to be IPA, you can enter the IPA part of the table directly without any extra typing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tipa} % not needed if you are using e.g. xelatex and an IPA font
% define a column for the IPA part of the footnote
\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\begin{IPA}[}p{#1}<{]\end{IPA}}}
% define a translation footnote command
\newcommand{\transfn}[3]%
{\footnote{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{1cm}I{1cm}p{6cm}}#1 & #2 & #3\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}
This is some text.\transfn{English}{INglIS}{translation}.
This is some more text.\transfn{another}{@n2D\textrhookschwa}{another translation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and it works, thanks! Although it would've been nice to have been able to put it all in one table, so I wouldn't have to set fixed widths.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to put them all into one table, so yes, you do have to set the column widths manually. But having a constant size from page to page will probably look better anyway.  Since you found this answer to have solved your problem, it's helpful to accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer.